# Imagick to Ghostscript equivalent command

Tags: google-sheets, command, ghostscript, imagick

I have an Imagick command and have to run it with Ghostscript.

The next Imagick command is:

```
convert -type grayscale -density 300 file.pdf file.tiff
```

How would it be the same but with Ghostscript?

Thanks in advance to this whole community.

Answer (score 1):

Rendering a PDF to TIFF with Ghostscript means using one of the Tiff output devices; there are several but you seem to want grayscale output, so tiffgray would be the most obvious candidate (--help will give you a list of available devices). Assuming -density means the resolution then you set that with -r.

So the final command would be:

```
gs -sDEVICE=tiffgray -r300 -o file.tiff file.pdf
```

You could also use the tiffscaled8 device which would allow you to render at a higher resolution and then scale down, in effect producing anti-aliasing.

The Ghostscript documentation is in ghostpdl/doc and online [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.53.1/Readme.htm), you probably want to read use.htm.

You might also be able to use the -debug switch to convert which **might** tell you how it is using Ghostscript. I'm not certain because I'm not an ImageMagick user.